# Run Quartz job at specified time

Tags: c#, .net, scheduler, quartz

I have a job in Quartz Scheduler which deletes rows from database and I want it to run everyday at 00:00. Currently it has intervalInMinutes set to 1440 (24hrs) but it's wrong. How to set this to run everyday at 00:00?

Code snippet:

```
x.AddTrigger(x => x,
.ForJob(delete)
.StartNow()
.WithSimpleSchedule(s => s
    .WithIntervalInMinutes(1440)
    .RepeatForever()
);
```

Comment: Is it not because you're using `.StartNow()`? If "now" is 3pm, then won't it run every day at 3pm? It seems you probably want `.StartAt` instead of `.StartNow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple configuration for a specific recurring job trigger which is like below :

```
ITrigger t = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("myTrigger")
        .ForJob("myJob")
        .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(0,0)) // execute job daily at 00:00
        .Build();
```

Comment: This solution is better than wat I have suggested. Thanks for sharing @Eldar

Answer (score 1):

I currently do not have access to an IDE so I can't check it out, but I have found this on the Quartz documentation, maybe this helps you in the right direction.

```
trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
.WithIdentity("trigger8") // because group is not specified, "trigger8" will be in the default group
.StartAt(DateBuilder.EvenHourDate(null)) // get the next even-hour (minutes and seconds zero ("00:00"))
.WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
    .WithIntervalInHours(2)
    .RepeatForever())
// note that in this example, 'forJob(..)' is not called 
//  - which is valid if the trigger is passed to the scheduler along with the job  
.Build();
```

Notice how they specify StartAt, maybe you can use that builder to start at 00:00 exactly.

Then with the `WithSimpleSchedule` set an interval for every 24 hours and repeat forever.

Good luck!

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron job expressions and here is a helpful link https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

```
private static readonly string ScheduleCronExpression = "0 * 0 ? * * *";

var trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1").WithCronSchedule(ScheduleCronExpression).Build();
```